# Cumulative Taxes MYSQL Sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to support cumulative taxes in my application. I allow my items to support multiple taxes (1 or 2). Currently the way I calculate how much total tax is included is by summing up each tax percent such as 4 and 8, and charge 12% tax. But with cumulative tax you need the second tax is calculated by (subtotal+tax1 amount) * tax2 percent. How can I do this in mysql in one query with the following table structure. (All I need to calculate is the total tax)

```
mysql> describe phppos_sales_items;
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sale_id            | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| item_id            | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| description        | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| serialnumber       | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| line               | int(3)        | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| quantity_purchased | double(15,2)  | NO   |     | 0.00    |       |
| item_cost_price    | decimal(15,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| item_unit_price    | double(15,2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| discount_percent   | int(11)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe phppos_sales_items_taxes;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sale_id    | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| item_id    | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| line       | int(3)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| percent    | double(15,2) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| cumulative | int(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is my current query that doesn't take the cumulative flag into effect:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE phppos_sales_items_temp (SELECT phppos_sales.deleted as deleted, date(sale_time) as sale_date, phppos_sales_items.sale_id, comment,payment_type, customer_id, employee_id, phppos_items.item_id, NULL as item_kit_id, supplier_id, quantity_purchased, item_cost_price, item_unit_price, category, SUM(percent) as item_tax_percent, discount_percent, (item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100) as subtotal, phppos_sales_items.line as line, serialnumber, phppos_sales_items.description as description, ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(1+(SUM(percent)/100)),2) as total, ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(percent)/100),2) as tax, (item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100) - (item_cost_price*quantity_purchased) as profit FROM phppos_sales_items INNER JOIN phppos_sales ON phppos_sales_items.sale_id=phppos_sales.sale_id INNER JOIN phppos_items ON phppos_sales_items.item_id=phppos_items.item_id LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_suppliers ON phppos_items.supplier_id=phppos_suppliers.person_id LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_sales_items_taxes ON phppos_sales_items.sale_id=phppos_sales_items_taxes.sale_id and phppos_sales_items.item_id=phppos_sales_items_taxes.item_id and phppos_sales_items.line=phppos_sales_items_taxes.line WHERE date(sale_time) BETWEEN "2011-07-28" and "2011-07-28" GROUP BY sale_id, item_id, line) UNION ALL (SELECT phppos_sales.deleted as deleted, date(sale_time) as sale_date, phppos_sales_item_kits.sale_id, comment,payment_type, customer_id, employee_id, NULL as item_id, phppos_item_kits.item_kit_id, '' as supplier_id, quantity_purchased, item_kit_cost_price, item_kit_unit_price, category, SUM(percent) as item_tax_percent, discount_percent, (item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100) as subtotal, phppos_sales_item_kits.line as line, '' as serialnumber, phppos_sales_item_kits.description as description, ROUND((item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(1+(SUM(percent)/100)),2) as total, ROUND((item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(percent)/100),2) as tax, (item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_kit_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100) - (item_kit_cost_price*quantity_purchased) as profit FROM phppos_sales_item_kits INNER JOIN phppos_sales ON phppos_sales_item_kits.sale_id=phppos_sales.sale_id INNER JOIN phppos_item_kits ON phppos_sales_item_kits.item_kit_id=phppos_item_kits.item_kit_id LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes ON phppos_sales_item_kits.sale_id=phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes.sale_id and phppos_sales_item_kits.item_kit_id=phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes.item_kit_id and phppos_sales_item_kits.line=phppos_sales_item_kits_taxes.line WHERE date(sale_time) BETWEEN "2011-07-28" and "2011-07-28" GROUP BY sale_id, item_kit_id, line) ORDER BY sale_id, line
```

OUTPUT:

```
+---------+------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+-------------+------+--------------+--------------------+---------+--------+------------+
| deleted | sale_date  | sale_id | comment | payment_type          | customer_id | employee_id | item_id | item_kit_id | supplier_id | quantity_purchased | item_cost_price | item_unit_price | category  | item_tax_percent | discount_percent | subtotal    | line | serialnumber | description        | total   | tax    | profit     |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+-------------+------+--------------+--------------------+---------+--------+------------+
|       0 | 2011-07-28 |       1 |         | Cash: $1,416.00<br /> |        NULL |           1 |       1 |        NULL | NULL        |               1.00 |          800.00 |         1200.00 | Computers |            18.00 |                0 | 1200.000000 |    1 |              | Best Computer ever | 1416.00 | 216.00 | 400.000000 |
|       0 | 2011-07-28 |       2 |         | Cash: $2,832.00<br /> |        NULL |           1 |    NULL |           1 |             |               1.00 |         1600.00 |         2400.00 | Computers |            18.00 |                0 | 2400.000000 |    1 |              |                    | 2832.00 | 432.00 | 800.000000 |
|       0 | 2011-07-28 |       3 |         | Cash: $14.52<br />    |        NULL |           1 |       4 |        NULL | NULL        |               1.00 |           10.00 |           12.00 | Test      |            20.00 |                0 |   12.000000 |    1 |              |                    |   14.40 |   2.40 |   2.000000 |
|       0 | 2011-07-28 |       4 |         | Cash: $2,904.00<br /> |        NULL |           1 |    NULL |           1 |             |               1.00 |         1600.00 |         2400.00 | Computers |            20.00 |                0 | 2400.000000 |    1 |              |                    | 2880.00 | 480.00 | 800.000000 |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+-------------+------+--------------+--------------------+---------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: Can you provide example records and expected output?  It would make it easier.

Comment: can you provide the query that you are using to calculate what you described?

Comment: How do you determine that tax is "the second"? Do you mean that it has 'cumulative' flag set?

Comment: Oh, and if the (sale_id, item_id, line) key is good enough for your sale items, it's probably good enough for the sale item taxes.  If you need to have multiple lines per line-item, you should add a `tax_id` column, as a FK to a tax table.  Having that `VARCHAR` as part of the key (which I'm assuming contains the *name* of the tax) is asking for trouble.  Granted, I'd still save off the percentage, but I wouldn't make it part of the key.  And why are `item_cost_price` and `item_unit_price` two *very* different types, when they are likely storing the exact same type?

Comment: @a1ex07 If the cumulative flag is set to 1 then that is the second tax.

Comment: @X-Zero sales_items_taxes I need the name and percent as there could be 2 taxes. I should probably be using decimal for both, but it is a legacy thing.

Comment: Having two taxes is perfectly fine.  However, you should still deal with this by having a separate table that contains the name (and a column for the *current* percentage), and using that table's id as part of the key.  `percentage` does not belong in the key (as it is a dependant value), but it does belong in the table, as it is part of the historical record.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivoting technique to get cumulative and normal percentage in 2 different columns

```
SELECT a.sale_id, a.item_id, a.line, 
IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN b.cumulative = 1 THEN b.percent END),0) as cum_pcnt,
IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN b.cumulative != 1 THEN b.percent END),0) as norm_pcnt
FROM phppos_sales_items a
INNER JOIN phppos_sales_items_taxes b ON 
(b.sale_id = a.sale_id AND b.item_id = a.item_id AND b.line = a.line)
GROUP BY a.sale_id, a.item_id, a.line
```

Now you can use the query above as a derived table and join it instead of `phppos_sales_items_taxes` table (the following query is just to demonstrate the approach, I definitely missed the point how you calculate cost and convert percentage to multiplier):

```
SELECT ..., SUM([your cost calculation]*sales_taxes.norm_pcnt) as tax1,
SUM([your cost calculation]*sales_taxes.norm_pcnt*cum_pcnt) as tax2
FROM  ....
INNER[or LEFT, whatever makes sense] JOIN 
([the query above goes here]) sales_taxes
```

Also, I strongly recommend to refactor your table structure - these composite PKs don't make any sense in your case; if you need combination of the fields to be unique, you don't have to make them part of primary key, use `UNIQUE` indexes/constraints instead.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I don't understand what is wrong with the way my composite primary keys. To uniquely identify a row in the sales_items_taxes table  I need sale_id, item_id, line, name, percent. If it was just sale_id, item_id, line it would be possible to have tax names that are the same

Comment: @Chris Muench: Just a couple of points against composite PKs. For example, if you had `id bigint unsigned auto_increment not null primary key` in `phppos_sales_items` and unique index on `sale_id,item_id,line` then you wouldn't have to store these 3 fields in `phppos_sales_items_taxes` (it would be enough to store just that id). Also, having a large PK increases the size (all indexes have a reference to PK).  I'd use composite PK only for tables that represent many-to-many relationship

Comment: Wait, you're charging for the *exact same tax* twice?  Just with different percentages?  There are so many problems with that...  Besides the fact that `percentage` *still* does not belong in that key, regardless.

Comment: In Cananda that have 2 taxes the first one is regular the second tax is the first tax + subtotal * TAX

Comment: @ X-Zero: It doesn't return the same tax twice. Instead of 2 rows , `cumulative=0, pcnt = 10; cumulative = 1, pcnt =4` it returns one: `cum_pcnt=4, norm_pcnt=10`).